# Use fsck to fix a corrupted exfat SD card that doesn't work on Android 12 anymore

Tags: android, sd-card, exfat, fsck

After my Android phone crashed it brings an **Issue with SD card** and asks me to reformat it in order to use it again.

Luckily, on my Linux computer (Manjaro) the SD card is recognised and read without any issues.
I have read into `fsck` and tried to use it. It does find two errors but doesn't fix it. I tried with the arguments `-y` and `-r`, the output is always the same:

```
sudo fsck -y /dev/mmcblk0p1  
fsck from util-linux 2.38.1
exfatfsck 1.3.0
Checking file system on /dev/mmcblk0p1.
File system version           1.0
Sector size                 512 bytes
Cluster size                128 KB
Volume size                 119 GB
Used space                  115 GB
Available space            4742 MB
ERROR: '1_5006037524565459906.tgs_198_198_nolimit.pcache2' is empty but start cluster is 0xbbecd.
ERROR: '1_5006037524565459906.tgs_198_198_nolimit.pcache2' is empty but marked as contiguous (0x20).
Totally 1925 directories and 20221 files.
File system checking finished. ERRORS FOUND: 2, FIXED: 0.
```

I reckon I am just missing a small thing and that it should be easy to fix the SD-card as it is actually working on my laptop.

The question is: How can I actually fix the errors that were found?

Comment: The best you can do is to backups the contents if still readable and use the phone to format it. If it keeps complaining about errors then it's time to replace it.

Comment: what is the question?

Comment: @JoepvanSteen The question is: How can I actually fix the errors?

Comment: I have the same problem, with a 400 gb sandisk card. I can resolve it  (temporarily) in Windows by right clicking in file explorer-> tools-> check for errors. Unforunately fsck does not seem to work to fix it. If it did then perhaps it could be resolved from within android, see https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/38745/check-and-fix-sd-card-errors-within-android-itself. Anecdotally, it seems to me that cards go "corrupted" much faster under android 12 than android 10.